# Handling typescript typings with eval

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write a definition file for the [webworker-threads](http://npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) npm library. In their documentation it says that you can create a new worker as follows:

```
let worker = new Worker(function() {
  this.postMessage('worker created');
  this.close();
});
```

The trick is that everything inside of that function that is used to construct the worker has access to the worker itself through a self variable. This is accomplished in their code by checking if the argument passed into `new Worker()` is a function, and if so calling eval on it. See [here](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads/blob/master/src/worker.js#L38).

I'm wondering how to duplicate this with my typings. So far I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
export class Worker {
    public onmessage: (event: any) => any;

    public thread: Thread;

    constructor(fn?: Worker | string); // <= Doesn't work because technically the function passed in isn't a worker, it just accesses the new Worker as if it were.

    public postMessage(data: any): void;

    public terminate(): void;

    public addEventListener(type: string, cb: (event: any) => any): void;

    public removeEventListener(type: string): void;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to imitate what they are doing or trying to use it? As they already provide you with a `Worker` class, why do you need to create your own?

Comment: You are aware that they don't really use `eval` right? It's their own implementation of eval in their c code

Comment: @NitzanTomer it still accomplishes a similar thing. Regardless the answer I was looking for was given by Rem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.0 that in Release Candidate [TS changelog](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-20) now you can write:

```
constructor(fn?: (this: Worker) => any);
```

In older TypeScript versions I can recommend to cast this to Worker inside callback.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Took me a while to find relevant [section](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions)